# GCD DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL what priority is it going to run on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, priority-queue

I am trying to understand what priority is going to be used to run dispatch blocks that are dispatched on a custom serial queue declared as:

> dispatch_queue_t queue =
>   dispatch_queue_create("com.purposeOfQueue.queue",
>   DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

So, here, I am only saying that "queue" is a serial queue. But, what priority is the system going to use for this queue. I know there's HIGH, DEFAULT, LOW, BACKGROUND.

I also know I could do this:

> dispatch_set_target_queue(queue, DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

Which would make it so the queue get a DEFAULT priority.

But if I just do what I showed above?

> dispatch_queue_t queue =
>   dispatch_queue_create("com.purposeOfQueue.queue",
>   DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

What priority is that going to use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's useful to note that from iOS 8 the creation of queues and their abilities have changed. You would use the following to get a serial queue with the lowest priority.

```
dispatch_queue_attr_t queueAttributes = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.abc.myQueue", queueAttributes);
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because "Quality of service" is the proper way to handle this now. By specifying the quality of service I inherently know what priority the queue will have.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't explicitly force a priority, it will use the "default" priority. This kinda goes right to the heart of the meaning of the word "default."

Comment: It makes sense. Is this found anywhere in Documentations or is it something you figured out somehow? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is explicitly stated anywhere in the documentation. As a native English speaker I feel like it kind of "goes without saying."

Comment: I'm sure you don't care anymore, but for posterity: if you look at queue.h of dispatch, the declaration of this function states: "When no quality of service class is specified, the target queue of a newly created dispatch queue is the default priority global concurrent queue."

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can accomplish what you're looking for with:

```
    dispatch_set_target_queue(queue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
```

or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` as the case may be.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know this. But, my question is what priority is given to the queue in case I just create without explicitly specifying the priority.

Comment: In that case I'm going to go with the various answers that boil down to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` :)

Answer (score -1):

Check the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6) of serial queues.

> Serial queues are useful when you want your tasks to execute in a specific order. A serial queue executes only one task at a time and always pulls tasks from the head of the queue. You might use a serial queue instead of a lock to protect a shared resource or mutable data structure. Unlike a lock, a serial queue ensures that tasks are executed in a predictable order. And as long as you submit your tasks to a serial queue asynchronously, the queue can never deadlock.

and from queue.h:

```
/*!
 * @const DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL
 * @discussion A dispatch queue that invokes blocks serially in FIFO order.
 */
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I am not seeing anything about "priority". What priority are the dispatched blocks on my "queue" going to get?

Comment: You can assume it's not the main priority because it's not on the main thread

Comment: There is no priority called 'main'.